# Change value if column contains value

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, formula

I have a drop down list in column G, and I want to change the current cell (which is J7) if text is found within column G.

This is what I have so far, however it does not work.

`=IF(FIND( "Fail" , G:G ),"Yes" ,"No" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`=IF(COUNTIF(F1:F100,"Fail")>0,"YES","NO")`